# If force is given by the negative gradient of potential, what gradient gives us a momentum field?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, momentum

Does this question make sense physically?

If we wanted to know the momentum of some particle moving through a field at some given point (assuming it's conservative), what function's gradient would tell us that?

Comment: Function's negative gradient gives you force -field which is rate of change of momentum.  Now from the equation of motion youll be able to momentum at certain instant.

Answer (score 2):

If $ \boldsymbol{F}=-\boldsymbol{\nabla}V $ and $ \frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt}=\boldsymbol{F} $, then $ \boldsymbol{p}=\boldsymbol{p_0}-\int_0^t\boldsymbol{\nabla}Vdt $. Take $ \phi=-\boldsymbol{p_0}\cdot \boldsymbol{r}+\int_0^tVdt $ and so then $ \boldsymbol{p}=-\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi $. I've never seen this before and I don't see its usefulness directly but there you go.

Comment: Why? $ \boldsymbol{\nabla}(\boldsymbol{p_0} \cdot \boldsymbol{r})=\boldsymbol{\nabla}(p_{0x}x+p_{0y}y+p_{0z}z)=(p_{0x}, p_{0y},p_{0z})=\boldsymbol{p_0} $